# I need to add people to access a specific folder, but not the whole page?

Tags: permissions

I need to add some people to edit a certain file in a folder, but they do not have access to the page it is located on.  Is that an issue?

Comment: You should be good to provide access to the file in the document library using item level security and provide the link to the user to the file in the document library. They will see only the documents they have access to view. Not sure what you mean by provide access to the page?

Answer (score 1):

At least the people should have read access to your site.

Otherwise they will get an access denied.

When using SharePoint 2013 you may try to "share" the folder and hope SharePoint will set permissions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Although a folder has been added to a page as an app, it will still be actually located on site-level scope (see `Site Contents`).

If the users don't have a permission to the site they can't access the folder although unique permissions have been added.